# Is this proof of the pythagorean theorem novel?

Tags: geometry

I know that the chances are, it's probably not new, but I want to know if it is or not anyways :)
-EDIT: I couldn't google this proof so I have no idea if it is already established
[image]

Comment: Congratulations for coming up with a proof on your own... Your picture looks like the one of proof 102 of https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/

Comment: Thanks! Guess this proof is partially novel, as it is similar to 102 but not identical to it.

Comment: You could also check Elisha Loomis' ["The Pythagorean Proposition" (PDF)](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED037335.pdf), which has 370 proofs.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me how you got $FB={a^2 \over b}-b$, nor is it clear how that satisfies the Pythagorean relationship.

Comment: I'll need to submit a photo for that, but I can't submit them in the comment section. Would you mind if I edit the post for some 'extra explaining'?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Some extra explanation on my proof

Comment: (Answering a question in your comment to the question) Editing your post is the appropriate way to add "extra explanation". ... Ideally, images should contain only diagrams (in the proper orientation! ;), with text written separately and mathematics entered as [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409); this makes a question more searchable, as well as accessible to readers who may have visual difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll try to implement it as soon as possible. Right now, the only stuff I have is my phone and my note, and I think I'll need to learn how to use Latex.